# Add a slide dynamically to flexslider with controlNav set to "thumbnails"

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am looking to dynamically add a slide to a felixslider instance that I instantiate on page load.

I tried the following code:

```
$('#product_slider_main').data('flexslider').addSlide("<li> slide </li>");
```

But that resulted in a `Maximum Call Stack exceeded error`

I am not sure how else I can dynamically add a slide to a flexslider.

My initial instantiation

```
  $('#product_slider_main').flexslider({
    startAt: parseInt($('.featured_image', $(this)).data('index'), 10),
    touch: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    controlNav: "thumbnails",
    directionNav: false,
    {% if settings.product_slideshow_animation == 'none' or settings.product_slideshow_animation == 'zoom' %}
    slideshow: false,
    {% else %}
    animation: "{{ settings.product_slideshow_animation }}",
    {% endif %}
    slideshowSpeed: {% if settings.slideshow_speed != blank %}{{ settings.slideshow_speed }}{% else %}10{% endif %}*1000,
    animationSpeed: 1
  });
```

Comment: have you resolved this problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The method of adding/appending a new slide to FlexSlider is correct but you're targeting incorrect DOM element.

In your initialisation, you've initiated flexslider on ***#product_slider_main*** so you should append new slide like this

```
$('#product_slider_main').data('flexslider').addSlide("<li> slide </li>");
```

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake when I typed out the question on SO. I do append the slide to the current element. I updated the question.